# Set ToolStripMenuItem mnemonic programmatically

Tags: vb.net, mnemonics

I am adding `ToolStripMenuItem`s to a menu based on the COM ports available on the machine, to allow the user to check one for use.

I'd like to add a mnemonic for each menu item such that the result would be the same as if I had manually added "COM&6" as the ToolStripMenuItem.Text property value.

However, using `PortName.Insert(3, "&")` doesn't seem to have any effect, or maybe I'm setting the text incorrectly?

How can I achieve this? Currently my full code for this segment is as follows:

```vb
For Each p As String In PortNames
    Dim tsmi As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem()
    tsmi.Name = p
    p.Insert(3, "&") 'This appears to do nothing
    tsmi.Text = p
    tsmi.CheckOnClick = True
    tsmi.Checked = False
    AddHandler tsmi.Click, AddressOf Me.PortSelectionTooStripMenuItem_Click
    CommunicationsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(tsmi)
Next
```

EDIT: I realised I probably dont actually want to do this as this will cause issues if the COM numbers move into double digits (e.g. COM&1 and COM&10 would be the same mnemonic). But I'd still be interested to find out how this *could* have been done and why my code did not work.

Comment: Strings are immutable so you must not forget to use the return value of Insert().  tsmi.Text = p.Insert(3, "&")

Comment: Your concern is a good one, but this is still commonly done in MRU lists. What they do is add mnemonics to the first 10 items (the 10th gets the mnemonic on the 0), and then not have mnemonics for the items beyond 10. Since the first 10 are probably the most commonly used, this is still helpful. Alternatively, duplicate mnemonics will work, the focus will just move between the duplicates each time the key is pressed. It just doesn't insta-toggle them.

Comment: @HansPassant & @ CodyGray Great, thanks! Do you feel like making that an answer Hans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansPassant commented, Strings are immutable and so `Insert()` must be used similar to a shared function.
That is, instead of:

```
p = tsmi.Name
p.Insert(3, "&")
tsmi.Text = p
```

I should instead use:

```
tsmi.Text = tsmi.Name.Insert(3, "&")
```